# JNI C++ Callbacks

Tags: java-native-interface

I have a c++ function which accepts a lambda as a parameter. This function calls a piece of java code.

I was wondering how would I get the java code to call the lambda once it's done, in effect calling back to the C++ code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[JavaCPP](https://github.com/bytedeco/javacpp) does that. For example, the following code in C++:

```
#include "jniFoo.h"

int main() {
    JavaCPP_init(0, NULL);
    foo(6, 7);
}
```

With this Java class:

```
import com.googlecode.javacpp.*;
import com.googlecode.javacpp.annotation.*;

public class Foo {
    public static class Callback extends FunctionPointer {   
        public @Name("foo") void call(int a, int b) { 
            System.out.println("bar " + a * b);
        }
    }
}
```

Produces the following output:

```
bar 42
```

Comment: @Jonny No, why does it matter? We want a closure in Java, right?

Comment: Because of "I was wondering how would I get the java code to call the lambda once it's done, in effect calling back to the C++ code."

Comment: The question was about calling from Java to C++, this sample is C++ calling Java, but it's cool

Comment: @AlexCohn The question isn't entirely clear, but if the argument is a `std::function`, I don't see any reason why we could not map that as any other class. Should I add some sample code for that case?

Comment: which argument is std::function?

Answer (score 0):

Java does not know C++ or lambdas. You should prepare a general C callback that will know which lambda to execute.

Comment: I was not precise. I ment, "Java does not know C++ or C++ lambdas". JNI callbacks are pure C. You can prepare wrappers if you wish.